# Fix indenting of script tag content in snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I answer many WebGL questions. In WebGL, especially as snippets, it's common to put GLSL in a script tag. Unfortunately SO won't correctly indent the content of a script tag

If I have some code like this

```
<script id="vertex-shader" type="not-js">
           void main() {
             gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
           }
</script>
```

I'd like to be able to select the lines between the script tags and indent/unindent them but SOs snippet editor doesn't respond to shift-tab for the content in script tags.

Here's an example showing usage and wanting a way to format the GLSL in the script tags without having to use an external editor.

Selecting the JavaScript and pressing Shift-Tab reformats that JavaScript. Selecting the script tag or the content inside the script tag and pressing shift-tab does nothing.

```js
"use strict";
var gl = twgl.getWebGLContext(document.getElementById("c"));
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);

var arrays = {
  position: [-1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
};
var bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

function render(time) {
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  var uniforms = {
    time: time * 0.001,
    resolution: [gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height],
  };

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
html, body, canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
        attribute vec4 position;

        void main() {
          gl_Position = position;
        }
</script>
<script id="fs" type="notjs">
        precision mediump float;

        uniform vec2 resolution;
        uniform float time;

        void main() {
          vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution;
          float color = 0.0;
          // lifted from glslsandbox.com
          color += sin( uv.x * cos( time / 3.0 ) * 60.0 ) + cos( uv.y * cos( time / 2.80 ) * 10.0 );
          color += sin( uv.y * sin( time / 2.0 ) * 40.0 ) + cos( uv.x * sin( time / 1.70 ) * 40.0 );
          color += sin( uv.x * sin( time / 1.0 ) * 10.0 ) + sin( uv.y * sin( time / 3.50 ) * 80.0 );
          color *= sin( time / 10.0 ) * 0.5;

          gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3( color * 0.5, sin( color + time / 2.5 ) * 0.75, color ), 1.0 );
        }
</script>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

## It's a *Feature Request*

This is tagged as a feature request. It is not a request for random hacky workarounds like exiting the snippet editor to edit the snippet (WAT?) or copying and pasting code from one section to another and back.

Of course workarounds are appreciated but SO is a site by programmers for programmers. In my experience most programmers given a pain point solve the pain by implementing a better solution, not by using convoluted workarounds.

Comment: Does the "tidy" button do anything? Also, you could just un-indent with Ctrl+k/ command+k when normally editing your post

Comment: Inside the snippet editor on OSX Ctrl-K deletes the selection inside a script tag. Cmd-K does nothing inside a script tag. Tidy completely destroys all formatting. I see that outside the snippet editor I can press Ctrl-K which does do something. Not really a good UX to have to exit the editor to actually edit but I suppose it's better than nothing.

Comment: OSX <-- Well, there's your problem ;-)

Comment: @cerbrus, same in Linux and Windows smart ass >:(

Comment: @Laurel, the Tidy button mangles the code, since it's pasted in the HTML section. I'm guessing it uses an HTML-specific tidy, since script is supposed to go into the JavaScript section. Since gman's trying to put "not-js" script in there, it doesn't know what to do. That said, one could cut the code from those script elements, paste it in the JavaScript section, run Tidy, then cut and paste the code back into the script section. Might be easier just to format after exiting the script editor.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on a Mac too and I can take the following code:

```
<script id="vertex-shader" type="not-js">
           void main() {
             gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
           }
</script>
```

I can press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> and get:

```
<script id="vertex-shader" type="not-js">
   void main() {
     gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
   }

</script>
```

Keep in mind you need to select the inner text like:

`<script id="vertex-shader" type="not-js">`

> ```
>       void main() {
>         gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
>       }
> ```

`</script>`

Depending on the indentation, you may need to press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> several times.

---

Stack Snippets only support JS, HTML, or CSS  anyway, so there's not much you can do there.

Comment: You can do that while in the snippets editor? I can do it outside the editor but it seems ridiculous to have to exit the snippet editor to actually edit the snippet.

Comment: @gman if you're working in the editor, why not just add the indentation while you type?

Comment: Because I'm often copying and pasting from somewhere else. That somewhere else is often indented differently from the way I need it on SO